# What happened to the question about tetris in 140 bytes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

There was a question about implementing Tetris in under 140 bytes, which I can not find. 
I started working on a solution a few hours ago, and now that it's working, I can't find it.  Was it closed *and* deleted that fast?

If so, can we undelete it? I realize it wasn't a great question but I'd like to try to salvage it.
 I'd add more objective criteria to make it a better question:

- Define the rules for "binary tetris"
- Require a complete runnable implementation, not just the board update function.
- Add a further restriction that the solution needed to be broken up into 140 byte lines. Each line would have to be a legal program when combined with the previous lines, although it wouldn't need to be functional until the full set is assembled.
- Winning criteria is fewest tweets, tiebreaker is most bytes to spare.  *(my score is 3/29)*

Answer (score 4):

It was deleted by the user who asked it. Here is the text from the question. Salvage away

I want to see if anyone can beat this:
http://www.i-programmer.info/news/167-javascript/3799-tetris-in-140-bytes.html
http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/02/19/1351213/tetris-in-140-bytes

As you can see, the rule set is simplified compared to real Tetris. However, we go by same rules as specified in the javascript version, hence the Binary Tetris.

Based on comments I understood, that the introduced javascript code covers only the basic logic of the game. Obviously it had some slashdot value, so try to make similar logic function with less than 140 bytes. Any language is welcome!